# Scrollbar bug in IE and Edge with transformX and margin

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

There is a weird bug in IE where if you use margin-left and transform: translateX you get a horizontal scrollbar.

It works fine in Chrome and Firefox.
Looking at it it's like IE keeps the space reserved even though the transform pulled the element back

Example site: http://site.brijn.com/dap/ (Works fine in chrome/firefox. Scrollbar in IE)

The code:

```css
.main {
    min-height: 650px;
    width: 80%;
    float: left;
    z-index: 21;
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
}

.center-transform {
    margin-left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
}
```

```html
<main class="main container center-transform" role="main" itemscope="" itemprop="mainContentOfPage">
    <!-- Content of element -->
</main>
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this an issue in IE.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it is a IE bug.
You are placing a big element in the center and so the "physical" place is 40% over the window. With transform, you place the graphical item back to the center.
You change the 2D graphical behaviour but not the physical behaviour of this object (this is still over the window, and so you will see the scrollbars).

If you know that your main is 80%, you can simply translate it to 10% (gives you the same result).

```css
.main {
    min-height: 650px;
    width: 80%;
    float: left;
    z-index: 21;
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
}

.center-transform {
    transform: translateX(10%);
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
}
```

```html
<main class="main container center-transform" role="main" itemscope="" itemprop="mainContentOfPage">
    <!-- Content of element -->
</main>
```

**Note:** main-tag is not supported in IE!